# AWS redrive to source queue in Java

Tags: amazon-sqs

AWs recently added a feature that allows you to send messages from a DLQ back to source queue via a lick of a button "redrive to source". I wanted to know is this possible via an API call.

I know how to extract a message from dlq queue and re send it, But with this new function i was hoping i wouldnt need to handle the messages, but rather just call a method perhaps on the queue and if its configured it would do the redelivery.

Anyone know if this is possible, as im searching in the net.

Comment: I believe currently this feature only available via the management console UI and not as an API

Answer (score 0):

I believe currently this feature is only available via the management console UI and not as an API